# difference between dispatcher and execution context in akka

Tags: akka

I have following actors:

```
val actor1 = context.actorOf(SorterActor.build
    .withDispatcher("akka.actor.custom-dispatcher"), name = "actor_child1")
val actor2 = context.actorOf(SorterActor.build
    .withDispatcher("akka.actor.custom-dispatcher"), name = "actor_child2")
```

and execution context

```
implicit val ec: ExecutionContext = context.system.dispatchers.lookup("akka.actor.custom-dispatcher")
```

Thing what I don't understand is what is difference between saying which dispatcher to use with `withDispatcher` fn on actor, and specifying execution context which point to the same dispatcher. What will happen if execution context is pointing to different dispatcher than one defined with `withDispatcher` function?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you specify a dispatcher while creating actors then this dispatcher will be used by those actors themselves (for messages processing).

When you define an `implicit val` with execution context it determines which execution context will be used by `Future`-s in scope of its definition (and of course you can use it explicitly for execute `Runnable`-s).

If the implicit execution context is pointing to different dispatcher than one defined with `withDispatcher` function then your `Future`-s will be run on that different dispatcher (not on actor's dispatcher). Often it can be useful for more granular bulkheading.